# Parsing using the xml

Tags: android, xml-parsing

I am trying to get some information from a xml file i have tried different links and it works but when i passed this url="http://www.w3schools.com/xml/simple.xml" it catches SAXexception
Here it is my code

```
public class XMLfunctions {

    public Document getDomElement(String xml){
        Document doc = null;
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        try {

            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

            InputSource is = new InputSource();
                is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xml));
                doc = db.parse(is);

            } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
                Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
                return null;
            } catch (SAXException e) {
                Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
                return null;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
                return null;
            }
                // return DOM
            return doc;
    }
```

It catches (SAXException e)
Can anyone help how i can avoid this problem??

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
 DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
 DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
 Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(response)));
// normalize the document
doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
 // get the root node
NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("your tag name");
```